# element-wise matrix min in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, min

This is weird.

I have a giant `10000x1` vectors (call it B), and `10000x1` vector (call it A) that only contains all ones.

I want to do element-wise min comparison of B and A.... such that `min(B(1),A(1))`, `min(B(2),A(2))`.... and so on.

So `C=min(B,A)`

I have  `B(1) = 0.85`, and `B(2) = 1.25`, when we are doing this `min`, I expect that `C(1)=0.85`, and `C(2)=1`.

However, the resulting C matrix has:  `C(1)=0.085`, and `C(2)=0.125`.  Why is this?

Comment: Give `A(1)` and `A(2)`

Comment: Either your `B(1)` and `B(2)` values aren't as given, or your `A` isn't all ones.

Comment: Post at least the first 10 values for A and B matrices.

Comment: Is `C(2)=0.125` or `C(2)=1.25`?

Comment: If you want to find out exact what went wrong in your code i recommend the profiler

Answer (score 5):

You could also do

```
C = ((A+B) - abs(A-B))/2;
```

Comment: +1 - This was one of the tricks I learned to calculate the minimum on my own without using `min`.

Comment: Interesting trick indeed! +1. So for `max` it would be `+ abs..`?

Comment: @Divakar Yep! It's a little bit tricky to know which sign to use, and to accept that the order `A-B` or `B-A` within `abs` is irrelevant. In fact I had to check with a small numerical example

Comment: @rayryeng It's more creative than `min` :-) Not necessarily faster, though

Comment: And this could also lead to floating point precision issues when compared against the actual min values of `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the full code and values it is hard to see what exactly is the problem, but obviously something is wrong or different than you describe.
See this example for how it would be done according to your description:

```
A = ones(5,1);
B = A*1000;
B(1)=0.85;
B(2)=1.25;
C = min(B,A)
```

Will produce:

```
C =

    0.8500    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

Changing the 5 into 10000 will of course not change the first two values of `C`.